# How does i Get Base Directory URL in zend framework 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am noobie at ZF3, We have placed zend based admin panel inside codeigniter based main app. like following way

```
my_app/zend_admin/
|
|
--- config
--- module
--- public
```

i can access zend module using `www.my_app.com/zend_admin/my_zend_controller/my_zend_action`.

I want to access `www.my_app.com/my_ci_controller/my_ci_action`.

**Is there any method zend provide as ci provides base_url() so i can fetch my ci controller??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get base URL you can use **serverUrl view helper** (like in codeigniter base_url())

```
$this->serverUrl();       // return http://web.com OR 
$this->serverUrl('/uri'); // return http://web.com/uri
```

I am not sure about your setup but try that...

Comment: Partially it works for me, On the server side its fine, but in localhost, its taking server url to localhost not to localhost/my_app .. how ever i can understand this. So accepting your answer as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can get this job done using ZF micro tools.

There are some similar view helpers in the ZF like CodeIgniter has. You can use them for the purpose in the view script and layout template.

Lets start up using `module.config.php` of your module. You can set up `base_path` key under `view_manager` key as follows

```
'view_manager' => [
    'base_path' => 'http://www.yoursite.com/',
]
```

Now if you use the following view helper

```
echo $this->basePath();
// Outputs http://www.yoursite.com/
```

If you use the following one

```
echo $this->basePath('css/style.css');
// Outputs http://www.yoursite.com/css/style.css
```

But if you do not use the above configuration

```
echo $this->basePath('css/style.css');
// Outputs css/style.css
```

As @tasmaniski said about `$this->serverUrl();` you can use that too in the view script. Good thing for this does not need any configuration like `$this->basePath()`

**What if** you need this **in the controller action** of ZF. The easiest way to do it in the controller action is

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $uri = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
    $baseUrl = sprintf('%s://%s/', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost());

    // Use this $baseUrl for your needs
    // Outputs http://www.yoursite.com/ 
}
```

Otherwise, you can get it the following way but this works same as `$this->basePath()`

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // This is for zf2
    $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');

    // This is for zf3
    // Assuming $this->serviceManager is an instance of ServiceManager
    $renderer = $this->serviceManager->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');

    $baseUrl = $renderer->basePath('/uri');

    // Use this $baseUrl for your needs
    // Outputs http://www.yoursite.com/uri   
}
```

Moreover, there are two more functions that can be used under different conditions in the controller actions. Those return empty string if rewriting rules used. Those are

```
$this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
$this->getRequest()->getBasePath();
```

These do not work as you expect I mean as you expect. Must refer to the [issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4214) to know why is this!

Comment: Thanks for such detail explanation.